# UIScrollViews frames after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

In app in second VC I have `UICollectionViewCell` with few images miniatures and after tap you segue to fullscreen with all images that are inside cell (for example if there is 3 images in cell (scrollview is inside) you segue with that three images to fullscreen presentation).
To display few images I'm using one scrollView inside another (solution found somewhere here, on StackOverflow).

On storyboard I have only main UIView. All other things I'm setting in code. I know, I should not use frames in code when using autolayout but it was nearly impossible to me to set proper constrains when using scrollview **with zoom** with rotations. And this solution I'm using only in `fullScreenVC`.

So, in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)]; 
self.outerScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];

self.outerScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.outerScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
self.outerScrollView.delegate = self;
self.outerScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self scrollViewDataForPortrait:NO];

[self.view insertSubview:self.outerScrollView belowSubview:self.blackInfoBox];
[self scrollToCurrentElement:[self.currentPictureToDisplay integerValue]];
```

scrollViewDataForPortatit:(BOOL) is method for populating inner scrollView with pictures and for setting frames, frames depends on orientation

```
- (void)scrollViewDataForPortrait:(BOOL)isPortrait
{
    for (int gadabout = 0; gadabout < [self.imagesToDisplay count]; gadabout++)
    {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.imageView.frame.size.width * gadabout;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.imageView.frame.size;

        UIScrollView *innerScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        if (isPortrait)
        {
            [newView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
        }
        newView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        newView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        UIImage *painting = [self.imagesToDisplay objectAtIndex:gadabout];
        if (painting)
        {
            [newView setImage:painting];
        }

        innerScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
        innerScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0f;
        innerScrollView.delegate = self;
        innerScrollView.tag = gadabout;

        [self.arrayForUIImageViewsForZooming addObject:newView];
        [innerScrollView addSubview:newView];
        [innerScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        [innerScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 768)];
        if (isPortrait)
        {
            [innerScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 1024)];
        }
        [self.outerScrollView addSubview:innerScrollView];
    }
    self.outerScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.outerScrollView.frame.size.width * self.imagesToDisplay.count, self.outerScrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

To handle rotations in willRotateTo... I'm removing old subviews and adding new with frames for portrait.

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    self.outerScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            [self.outerScrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
            [self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
            [self.outerScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
            [self.arrayForUIImageViewsForZooming removeAllObjects];
            [self scrollViewDataForPortrait:NO];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
                [self scrollToCurrentElement:[self.currentPictureToDisplay integerValue]];
            } completion:nil];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            [self.outerScrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
            [self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
            [self.outerScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
            [self.arrayForUIImageViewsForZooming removeAllObjects];
            [self scrollViewDataForPortrait:YES];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
                [self scrollToCurrentElement:[self.currentPictureToDisplay integerValue]];
            } completion:nil];
        }];
```

Unfortunately the downside of this solution is fact that after rotation scrollview scrolls to first element and I'm programatically scroll to previous (current) position in scrollview.
That change is noticeable to user which is not want I want.

I also tried to set frames of all views and subviews in willRotate but after that scrollviews behavior is strange.

How to properly handle rotations when using two scrollviews (one inside another) and display images correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I also tried to set frames of all views and subviews in willRotate but after that scrollviews behavior is strange."

So this was proper solution to fix the problem.
I did with this piece of code, for example to set proper frame to all subviews before rotation to landscape.

```
    int gadabout = 0;
    for (UIScrollView *innerScrollView in self.outerScrollView.subviews)
    {
        [innerScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(1024 * gadabout, 0, 1024, 768)];    
        if ([innerScrollView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        {
            [innerScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 768)];
        }    
        for (UIImageView *innerImageView in innerScrollView.subviews)
        {
            [innerImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        }
        gadabout++;
    }
```